# Google Drive access Issue : Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException:

Tags: .net, google-drive-api

Google Drive Access from an Application:
Not able to upload or create folder in drive using google account with different domain in our application.

When tried, below is the exception thrown.

**Exception** : Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Unauthorized", Uri:""
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at myclass.CreateFolder() in C:\inetpub\websites\XXX\YYYY\abc.vb:line 103

Cross verified all settings, everything looks good
4. Verified Authorized URL in Console developers (Google Cloud platform).
5. Verified Google Drive is enabled in Console developers.
6. Verified Client Administrator API Access, scopes, Services.

[image]

[image]

Am I missing anything here? kindly provide suggestions on resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Unauthorized", Uri:"" at

Means that the requests you are making to Google Drive have not be authenticated.  In order to access private data you need to send the Access token with all of the requests you are making.

Check your code and makes sure that all calls to the api have been authenticated.